# In ruby console, how to update instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named "Person".
In ruby console, I first declare an instance of Person, then I update the attributes, then save.

```
person = Person.last
person.name = "jeff"
person.save
```

After doing these, I got message like this:

```
   (9.9ms)  BEGIN
   (7.5ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

What are "BEGIN", "ROLLBACK", "false" refers to separately?
I googled, but nothing came out.

Comment: That looks like you have some sql logging redirecting to your console.  It looks like `person` failed to save for some reason.  Try `person.errors.full_messages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `save` in Rails, it wraps the database operation in a transaction. `BEGIN` is written to the log when the transaction starts and `ROLLBACK` is logged if the operation fails (because all write operations in the transaction—`UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE`—are "rolled back").

`false` is the value that `save` returns when the operation fails.

You usually want to use [`save!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) instead of `save` because it will raise an (informative) exception if the operation fails.

Comment: This is a great explanation of what is causing the behavior in the question, but saying one "usually" wants `save!` is too strong.  Using `save!` is qualitatively different than `save` and shouldn't be thrown around in production code (unless you _like_ using exception handling for control flow...)

Comment: It's funny, usually if I write `save` in an answer someone comes along to say "You should use `save!` instead!"

Comment: heh, sorry to buck the trend.  In *this* case `save!` would definitely be useful for sure.  I just bristle at the implication that it's the right choice for, say, arbitrary production code.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at `update_attributes`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html